# Find the name of the user who has rated the greatest number of movies

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Table: Movies

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| movie_id      | int     |
| title         | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
```

movie_id is the primary key for this table.
title is the name of the movie.
Table: Users

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| user_id       | int     |
| name          | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
```

user_id is the primary key for this table.
Table: Movie_Rating

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| movie_id      | int     |
| user_id       | int     |
| rating        | int     |
| created_at    | date    |
+---------------+---------+
```

(movie_id, user_id) is the primary key for this table.
This table contains the rating of a movie by a user in their review.
created_at is the user's review date.

Write the following SQL query:

> Find the name of the user who has rated the greatest number of movies.
> In case of a tie, return lexicographically smaller user name.

> Find the movie name with the highest average rating in February 2020.
> In case of a tie, return lexicographically smaller movie name.

The query is returned in 2 rows, the query result format is in the following example:

Movies table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| movie_id    |  title       |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | Avengers     |
| 2           | Frozen 2     |
| 3           | Joker        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Users table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| user_id     |  name        |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | Daniel       |
| 2           | Monica       |
| 3           | Maria        |
| 4           | James        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Movie_Rating table:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| movie_id    | user_id      | rating       | created_at  |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1            | 3            | 2020-01-12  |
| 1           | 2            | 4            | 2020-02-11  |
| 1           | 3            | 2            | 2020-02-12  |
| 1           | 4            | 1            | 2020-01-01  |
| 2           | 1            | 5            | 2020-02-17  | 
| 2           | 2            | 2            | 2020-02-01  | 
| 2           | 3            | 2            | 2020-03-01  |
| 3           | 1            | 3            | 2020-02-22  | 
| 3           | 2            | 4            | 2020-02-25  | 
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Result table:

```
+--------------+
| results      |
+--------------+
| Daniel       |
| Frozen 2     |
+--------------+
```

Daniel and Monica have rated 3 movies ("Avengers", "Frozen 2" and "Joker") but Daniel is smaller lexicographically.
Frozen 2 and Joker have a rating average of 3.5 in February but Frozen 2 is smaller lexicographically.

answer1:

```
(select name results
from users
where user_id in (
    select user_id
    from movie_rating
    group by user_id
    having count(user_id) = (
        select max(cnt)
        from (
            select count(user_id) cnt
            from movie_rating
            group by user_id) f1))
order by results
limit 1)
union 
(select title results
from movies
where movie_id in(
    select movie_id
    from movie_rating
    where left(created_at,7) = '2020-02'
    group by movie_id
    having avg(rating) =(
        select max(avgr) 
        from (
            select avg(rating) avgr
            from movie_rating
            where left(created_at,7) = '2020-02'
            group by movie_id)f2))
order by results
limit 1)
```

answer2:

```
(
select name
from users u
join (
    select user_id, count(*) cnt
    from movie_rating
    group by user_id
    order by cnt
    limit 1) f1
on u.user_id = f1.user_id)
union
(
select title
from movies m
join (
    select movie_id, avg(rating) avgr
    from movie_rating
    where left(created_at,7) = '2020-02'
    group by movie_id
    order by avgr
    limit 1) f2
on m.movie_id = f2.movie_id)
```

both are wrong

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  It does in SQLite.

```
SELECT name FROM (
   SELECT u.name name, count(*) total 
   FROM users u, movie_rating mr 
   WHERE u.user_id=mr.user_id
   GROUP BY u.name
) ORDER BY total desc, name 
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT title FROM (
  SELECT m.title title, AVG(mr.rating) average 
  FROM movies m,  movie_rating mr 
  WHERE m.movie_id=mr.movie_id 
    AND created_at BETWEEN '2020-02' and '2020-03' 
  GROUP BY title
) ORDER BY average desc, title 
LIMIT  1;
```

Notice the strategy. Construct the aggregate number with the name in the inside query, then sort and pick the top in the outside query

Comment: Notice the strategy.  Construct the aggregate number with the name in the inside query, then sort abd pick the top in the outside query.

Comment: You're better off adding the explanation as part of the answer... comments often get deleted over time.